# Why FutureProvider build two times?

Tags: flutter, flutter-riverpod

When I build the code like below with using `FutureProvider`, the part `//here` executed two times, like followings;

1. `flutter: AsyncLoading<dynamic>()`
2. `flutter: AsyncData<dynamic>(value: World)`

I could not understand why this happens, and basically meanings of watch(), in FutureProvider context.
Based on [doc](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/), `watch()`says like
it's continuously watching changing in value of provider and when it is happened, UI might rebuild automatically.

What is meanings of changing especially in FutureProvider (Is it `Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3))` itself shown the sample below ?), and is it related to the two times execution problem, mentioned above?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'FutureProvider',
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: const TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 50)),
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

final futureProvider = FutureProvider<dynamic>((ref) async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
  return 'World';
});

class HomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final asyncValue = ref.watch(futureProvider);
    print(asyncValue);//here
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Hello World')),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
        onPressed: () {
          ref.refresh(futureProvider);
        },
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: asyncValue.when(
          error: (err, _) => Text(err.toString()),
          loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(), 
          data: (data) => Text(data.toString()), 
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your build may be called up to 60 times every second.  You should be prepared for that and ensure that build is fast and idempotent, particularly not performing I/O.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but could not understand. Thats why print executed twice ?